# Create/form e-mail in Java Web App

Tags: java, string, email, coding-style

Is there a better or less ugly way to form e-mails inside a Java web app?  I am currently using ALOT of static final Strings to represent both default property and the names of property settings.  I then combine all of those and send out the e-mail.

My current e-mail class contains the following:

1. Static final Strings that are the names of settings in a properties
       file.
2. Static final Strings that are default properties if the
       setting isn't found.
3. An injected class that actually sends the
       e-mail.
4. Methods that form and send the e-mail.

The current set-up is messy and just feels wrong, anything simpler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Velocity may be just the ticket for you.  Briefly here, 
https://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Email+Velocity+Template

and at http://velocity.apache.org

Comment: Just what I was looking for. I still have more string literals than i'd like, but this definitely cuts down on the boilerplate and brittle String-concatenation code.  Thanks.